# R : Plot many boxplot in the same graph using dataframe

Tags: r

Hello everyone and thank you for helping me with R.

i have a 39cols * 168rows matrix which looks like this :

[image]

and i want to plot boxplot (1 for each row) in the same graph.

Two hours of intense research on how to make that and i still have no clue.

What i tried (f is the read.csv i got ) :

```
boxplot(x = as.list(as.data.frame(f)))
qp <- boxplot(x = as.list(as.data.frame(f)))
rn <- as.numeric(rownames(f))
plot(qp,rn)
```

and i've got : 
*Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ*

even if i do not know if the result of the plot was the thing i wanted.

Comment: Tell us what `f` is. Is it the matrix? Why not just do `boxplot(f)`?

Comment: i want 1 boxplot for each line. My goal is to have a full graph with 168 boxplot next to each other. F is the matrix, i got it with 


f <- read.table("............",sep=",", fill = TRUE, header = FALSE, na.strings= " ")

Answer (score 0):

If you want one box per row, you need to transpose the matrix before passing it to `boxplot`:

```
boxplot(t(f))
```

This will then do the right thing — provided you’ve read in your data correctly. In your image, this isn’t the case: the header columns are (incorrectly) part of the data. Be sure to pass `header = TRUE` to your data reading function to fix this.